# CSS: How to align vertically a "label" and "input" inside a "div"?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

Consider the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/s2qBw/3/):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for='name'>Name:</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

What would be the easiest method to put the `label` and the `input` in the middle of the `div` (vertically) ?

Comment: To my knowledge, the bottom line is "you can't", and the laziest way around it is to use a simple `<table>` and apply `valign='middle'` to its `<td>` s.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```css
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for='name'>Name:</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' />
</div>
```

The advantages of this method is that you can change the height of the `div`, change the height of the text field and change the font size and everything will always stay in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/6/

Comment: looks elegant :) does anyone know how browser compatible this method is?

Comment: For IE, I think it only works on IE8 or better. For the other web browsers it's fine.

Comment: I didn't know about the `display: table-cell`.  Is that supported on certain browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work if the `input` / `label` absolutely positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/7/ Any ideas how to handle this ?

Comment: @Misha you should have specified the fact that your input / label were absolutely positioned. That totally changes the circumstances of the question. I am giving Marc a +1. Great answer.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the point jenson was trying to make (and should have articulated) is that using `display: table-cell` makes divs behave in ways they aren't expected to behave in, such as subsequent divs rendering on the same line/etc.

Comment: Note that this solution will not work if you have set your label to `float:left` because `label` becomes a `block` element with that attribute.

Comment: Use Flexbox instead

Comment: i have a problem with this solution: I'm already in a `div` which is `display:inline-block` (which I can't change) and creating another `div` inside it which is `display:table-cell` appears to do nothing to provide vertical alignment.

Comment: the problem is not with the solution, it is with the markup you are stuck with. i know that doesn't help, so to clarify, i am not being snarky here. that solution as is works fine. your constraints wouldn't lead to this desired solution, etc.

Comment: this would not work with float property on Div, it's better to user line height in that case.

Comment: This doesn't work when you have two or more divs following each other. They will be placed horizontally rather than vertically.

Answer (score 90):

A more modern approach would be to use [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for='name'>Name:</label>
  <input type='text' id='name' />
</div>
```

A more complex example: If you have multiple elements in the flex flow, you can use `align-self` to align single elements differently to the specified align.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

* {
  margin: 10px
}

label {
  align-self: flex-start
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://de.gravatar.com/userimage/95932142/195b7f5651ad2d4662c3c0e0dccd003b.png?size=50" />
  <label>Text</label>
  <input placeholder="Text" type="text" />
</div>
```

It's also super easy to center horizontally and vertically:

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for='name'>Name:</label>
  <input type='text' id='name' />
</div>
```

Comment: I wish this would work when there is an image and text wrapped in the label. I have a small icon followed by text, but the text doesn't budge.

Comment: it works if label and text are seperate elements, or if your make your lable a flexbox too...

Comment: `display:flex` has less compatibility , works on **chrome 29+**

Answer (score 15):

This works cross-browser, provides more accessibility and comes with less markup. 
ditch the div. Wrap the label

```
label{
     display: block; 
     height: 35px; 
     line-height: 35px; 
     border: 1px solid #000; 
}

input{margin-top:15px; height:20px}

<label for="name">Name: <input type="text" id="name" /></label>
```

Comment: This obviously won't work for a two line label. And if you are sure that label is always single line, than there are millions of other alternatives.

Comment: the question was in regards to a single line label, and i answered accordingly. not sure about your point(s) or intentions here, but if x is so obvious you should go make a million examples of it. at the very least so you can gloat under my answer and feel the power of your million victories. bravo.

Comment: This is the best answer for single line labels. The specification says: "If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable form-associated element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control." Therefore this is the only approach where you can omit the `for` and `id` attributes for maximum simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

I'm aware this question was asked over two years ago, but for any recent viewers, here's an alternative solution, which has a few advantages over Marc-François's solution:

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Here we simply only add a `line-height` equal to that of the height of the div. The advantage being you can now change the display property of the div as you see fit, to `inline-block` for instance, and it's contents will remain vertically centered. The accepted solution requires you treat the div as a table cell. This should work perfectly, cross-browser.

The only other advantage being it's just one more CSS rule instead of two :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Use `padding` on the `div` (*top and bottom*) and `vertical-align:middle` on the `label` and `input`.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLFeV/1/

Comment: That doesn't work on the jsfiddle. I changed the height of the `div` and the content inside didn't move at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: In my opinion, layouts shouldn't have fixed pixel heights… Layouts should flow fluidly around the content. However, I come from a day and time when browsers scaled text sizes when zooming in and out. Recent browsers actually scale the whole page, so setting pixel heights works a little better. However, there are whole new reasons to avoid setting pixel heights… for example, responsive layout techniques. That's why this would be my preferred method.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the label and input in another div with a defined height.  This may not work in IE versions lower than 8.

```
position:absolute; 
top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell` property as in the following code:

```
div {
     height: 100%;
     display: table-cell; 
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
```