# Vertically align input next to word-wrapped label with support for non-wordwrapped label?

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/9ctTD/18/

I have some labels which may or may not wordwrap. When the label wordwraps, my input element vertically aligns to the bottom of the containing div. I would like my input element to align with the center of the word-wrapped element.

I was able to achieve this through use of `vertical-align: 50%`, but this had the negative side-effect of breaking alignment for non-wordwrapped label/input pairs.

I had a look at [this StackOverflow post regarding alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466596/css-how-to-align-vertically-a-label-and-input-inside-a-div), but it appears to solve a different issue than the one I am experiencing.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label {
  max-width: 80px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

​

Comment: Huh. Css is an odd beast even after years of practice. Could've sworn I had tried that, but apparently I had not! Thank you!