# How to vertically center a label on a range input

Tags: css, html

This seems like it would be so simple but its giving me quite a bit of trouble. I've tried using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466635/2382483) already and it doesn't seem to work, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/. Floating the label and the input seems to be a step in the right direction but I still can't quite figure it out.

jsfiddle code:

```
<div>
    <label for="myslider">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" id="myslider" min="1" max="100" />
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/17/

^This seems to work in the latest versions of chrome, firefox, and ie.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: How to align vertically a "label" and "input" inside a "div"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466596/css-how-to-align-vertically-a-label-and-input-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to center the elements vertically

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div label
{
    vertical-align:middle;

}

#myslider
{
    vertical-align:middle;

}
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/16/

Comment: This looks great in chrome and firefox but not great in ie. Can't win em all though.

Comment: This got me most of the way to the solution I just added to my original question. Thanks!

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp No worries

Answer (score 4):

With **flexbox**, we now have another solution available. All we need is `align-items`:

```css
div {
  /* Use flexbox and center items vertically */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* The following aren't needed, they just help us to see the effect */
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px dotted #555;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="myslider">Slider:</label>
  <input id="myslider" type="range" min="1" max="100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the vertical alignment:

In HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="myslider">Slider:</label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" />
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
 div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.lblFloat
{
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/4/

Comment: Yeah thats what I got when I floated them but it still doesn't really look centered to me. If you add a border to the label you can see its not really centered in the div: jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/14/, nor is it centered if you remove the float: jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/15/

Answer (score -1):

I added this css to the label contained within your div:

```
div label {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

It will center the label above the slider, which I believe is what you're asking for.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ENuLz/2/)

Comment: Sorry my title wasn't clear. I want to vertically center them, not horizontally above or below.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
label {    
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my title wasn't clear. I want to vertically center them, not horizontally above or below.

Comment: You can add a margin-top to both elements, I'd recommend using developer tools so you can quickly adjust until pixel perfect.