# Centering lables and input text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following  tag with input text fields with labels

```
<div>

    Start Date:
    <input type="date" id="reportsStartDate">

    End Date:
    <input type="date" id="reportsEndDate">

</div>
```

and it looks like this

[image]

as you can see the labels for the text boxes are at the lower part of the text boxes. How do i set this so the labels are centered to the text boxes like below?

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9sa9ugof/

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` of the problem

Comment: take look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466596/css-how-to-align-vertically-a-label-and-input-inside-a-div

Comment: I crerated a fiddle wtih this code and on chrome labels and inputs are vertically centered

Comment: It already works like your required output.

Comment: Please include all the relevant CSS as well as HTML that replicates your issue.

Comment: inspect for `line-height, margins, paddings` these causes the issue and should be used properly.

Comment: can you show your jsffidle that is not working for you.?

Answer (score 0):

`Vertical-align: middle` is needed. If your input is a `display:inline-block` it works.

Answer (score -2):

You can add padding to the labels align it with the same height as that of inputs for that you need to include say a  and inside that give your labels.