# Vertically center input inside a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to have the `input` fields vertically centered inside each div viz. `color-1` `color-2` `color-3`
Using `vertical-align: middle` either in each div or `input` is not working.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="text"]  {
  width:150px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#color-1 {

  height: 33%;
  background: {{yourName}};
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#color-2{
  height: 33%;
  background: {{color_2}};
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#color-3{
  height: 33%;
  background: {{color_3}};
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="color-1">
  <input type="text" ng-model="color_1" placeholder="Enter Color #1">
  <h1>{{color_1}}</h1>
</div>

<div id="color-2">
  <input type="text" ng-model="color_2" placeholder="Enter Color #2">
  <h1>{{color_2}}</h1>
</div>

<div id="color-3">
  <input type="text" ng-model="color_3" placeholder="Enter Color #3">
  <h1>{{color_3}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: can u plz make a jsfiddle of it so that its easy to understand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466596/css-how-to-align-vertically-a-label-and-input-inside-a-div

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this in two ways using `display:flex` or using `display:table,display:table-row and display:table-cell` which you need to wrap in another div.

Using display:flex is better in which you no need to wrap template in another div

Add the class `color` for all the color divs

Style of 'color' class

```
.color{
   height:33%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items:center;
}
```

For more info refer this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I had made [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xwvq4chj/)

```
 #color-1 
{
    height: 33%;
    background: {{yourName}};
    vertical-align: top;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

}
```

and make divs

> align="center"

Comment: I am losing the horizontal alignment :(

Comment: I removed text-align:center