# How to center vertical alignment of text next to range input slider

Tags: html, css

I have a range input slider with text either side that I would like to align differently.

Ideally I don't want to change the text size if I can help it, but would consider it as a last resort (I have tried already tried it and it didn't work).

Also, I have already tried the suggestions as outlined in this question:
[CSS: How to align vertically a "label" and "input" inside a "div"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466596/css-how-to-align-vertically-a-label-and-input-inside-a-div)

Here is my html:

```
  <div>
    <span class="slider-left"><span id="slider-reset" class="slider-reset">Label</span></span><span class="slider-center"><input id="slider" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100"></span><span id="slideroutput" class="slider-output slider-right"></span>
  </div>
```

and my css:

```
.slider-left {
width: 75px;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
}

.slider-center, .slider {
width: 170px;
}

.slider-right {
width: 50px;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 10px;
float: right;
}
```

and this is how it looks:

[image: screenshot of slider with text in need of vertical alignment]

As you can see, the text feels like it's a few pixels too high up compared to the slider, the centre of which appears to be aligned to the bottom of the text.
I would like the horizontal centre of the slider bar to be aligned with the horizontal centre of the text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @DacreDenny I'm using Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Josef no problems - I've just posted an answer that should resolve the vertical alignment issue regardless of the font being used. Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [using flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to resolve the vertical alignment issue as outlined below:

```css
.slider {
  /* Use flexbox for slider wrapper element */
  display:flex;
  /* Direct alignment of content along horizontal axis */
  flex-direction:row;
  /* Tell's flexbox to center content around the non-horizontal axis (ie around the vertical axis) */
  align-items:center;
}

.slider-label {
  width:75px; 
}

.slider-input {
  /* Causes the input element to horizontally stretch to fill in available horizontal space */
  flex:1;
}

.slider-value {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span class="slider-label">Label</span>
  <input id="slider" class="slider-input" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" />
  <span id="slideroutput" class="slider-value">100</span>
</div>
```

To get a better feel for how flexbox works, you might find these interactive playgrounds helpful:

- [Flexbox Playground](https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/)
- [Flexy Boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)