# Align ASP checkbox CSS label styling

Tags: c#, css, checkbox

I am using an ASP checkbox within a website I have built. The problem I'm having is that the text is aligning with the top of the checkbox because I've applied:

```
display: inline !important;
```

This is much better than if I don't add this, because otherwise it sits at the top of the space and not anywhere near the checkbox! However it looks like it is sitting a little high. Is there an easy way to make the text sit in the middle next to the checkbox? I've included a screenshot to show what I mean.

I'm not very experienced with CSS but I've tried adding margins and padding and neither have worked.

My code looks like this:

C#

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Text is a little high" class="form-check-input" CssClass="chkbx_inline_top"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chkbx_inline_top label {
    color: red !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

[image: Picture showing text in red that I would like to move down]

With the suggestion below and doing some more googling, I have now also tried this without luck:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39939769/1860687

```
.chkbx_inline_top{
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.chkbx_inline_top label {
    align-self: flex-start !important;
}
```

But it hasn't worked for me:

[image: Flex styling]

Comment: Try to all this style .chkbx_inline_top{display:flex;align-items:center;}

Comment: @JaswinderKaur that makes the text sit underneath the checkbox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this in the end by a comnbination of the two suggestions I recieved. Posting it here in case it helps someone else!

```
.chkbx_inline_top {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.chkbx_inline_top label {
    align-self: flex-start !important;
    margin-bottom: -5px !important;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check styling of your input element in browser, there is a default styling for input elements something like this:

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px \9;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Then you can fix it with a styling in css to set margin of input element to 0,
something like this:

```
.chkbx_inline_top input[type=checkbox]{
    margin:0;
}
```